# In MVC, how do I return the previous page View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a post action in my MVC something along the line of:

```
    public ActionResult FilterData() {
        // Do some work
        // ....
        if (lastView != null) {
            return View(lastView);
        }
        return View("Default");
    }
```

Where do I find "lastView" so I can return the user to wherever they were at before postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide the URL as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult FilterData(string redirectUrl = null)
{
    // Do some work
    // ....
    if (redirectUrl != null) {
        return this.Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }

    return View("Default");
}
```

Comment: how do I get the redirectURL in view?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: This:  return this.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

This would not scale very well, but you could create another/edit the ActionResult to pass in a parameter from the View you just came from:

```
ActionResult FilterData(previousViewName)
{
    if (lastView !< null)
    {
        return View(previousViewName);  // or RedirectToAction(previous'controller'Name)
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```